# Python3 : 'mushroom' object not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Recently, I have started to create a Mario clone using python3 and pygame. So far,I have managed to get the base game working but there's a issue with mushrooms.

Whenever I bump the block, the block bumps, changes to empty block. The mushroom plays a animation and starts moving and it has gravity,movement and collision. The player can eat it to increase score or size.

BUT,

If I go and bump another mushroom block, this error occurs.

> TypeError: 'mushroom' object is not callable
>   engine.py, line 789***

This is where the error arises:

```
if mushroomblock.bumpingfinish:   
        empty_what_blocks.append(empty_what_block(mushroomblock.loc)) # Make a empty block at the location of the mushroom block after Mario bumps on it.        
        mushrooms.append(mushroom(mushroomblock.loc)) # Create a mushroom object at the location of the mushroom block
        mushroom_blocks.remove(mushroomblock) # Remove the coin object from the location.
```

Why is the object callable at first and then not when I try to call it again?

I have searched for solution everywhere and tried to fix it first but I couldn't find anything that would help me. I hope someone has a solution for this.

Comment: Since you provided only a small part of the code it's hard to see what's going on. What is `mushroom`? Looks like it is a class. In that case I suggest sticking to the naming conventions of the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and name it `Mushroom`(capital M) instead. For me it's easier to spot errors if I follow the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mushrooms.append(mushroom(mushroomblock.loc))` you are trying to call `mushroom` when it is not a class or function.
You might have made an instance of the class `mushroom()` called `mushroom` and the error occurs when it tries to call the instance. You need to rename one of them, You could rename the class `Mushroom` with a capital `M`.